# Stack Exchange- Area 51 Android App

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, android-app

I am trying to use Stack Exchange Andoid App to use my accounts in Stack Overflow & Area 51.

1. For the Area 51, there is only Area 51 Discussion.
2. Even Area 51 Discussion isn't working in the App!

**VERSION 1.0.51**

When adding this site, it's showing the correct full name as in this screen-shot:

[image: Screenshot 1]

However, when I pin this site to my fav sites in Stack Exchange, it is showing: `Unknown Site`.
When clicking it, it shows black screen then just quit the App! 
Here is the screen-shot:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Is the site not yet capable with Android? or is it a bug in the App itself?

**PS:** this question isn't duplicate:

1. In the previous versions of the App, the site was opening but with *Unknown Site* name. However, in this version, it quits the app when pressing the area site! It isn't opening at all!
2. This question is also to track this bug in the App. As it's about the site name issue & the content as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the future, you can post questions about Area 51 in the [Area 51 Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com).

However, this question is fine here.

Area 51's layout is a bit different from other Stack Exchange sites in that it doesn't really use the Q/A format to structure posts, and you're looking at *site proposals with questions* rather than questions on their own.

Accordingly, Area 51 is not included in the [Stack Exchange API](//api.stackexchange.com) (see [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/sites) for all of the sites) and thus is not included in the Android or iOS Stack Exchange applications.

Comment: Official app questions belong only here in MSE. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard True; that was more of a response to the OP's note at the end.