# Area51 SE is not available on the DE iOS app

Tags: support, area-51, mobile-app

Is there a reason for the fact that Area 51 is not available on mobile? Will Area 51 be available on the mobile version of the SE app soon?

Comment: While this question is about the Android app instead, the answer there is relevant here too: [Stack Exchange- Area 51 Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240533/stack-exchange-area-51-android-app). The layout is completely different, and the Area 51 site isn't exposed in the API.